# Ordenar o conteúdo do MetroGridView pelo click no titulo do Heder de uma determinada coluna

Tags: .net, linq, classificação, order, metroframework

ola pessoal estou com um problema, que venho a lutar já a algum tempo.
eu estou usando na minha aplicação MetroFramework e linq,e reparei que o MetroFramework nao tem determinadas propriedades ou que elas não funcionam como deve ser, ou entao eu que nao estou a fazer correcto.

eu faço o populat num Metrogrid e depois pretendo ordenar esta grid ao click do heder, em ordem crescente ou decrescente (a-z e z-a), mais a propriedade sort nao esta a fazer nem de forma automatica nem de forma programatic, ja fiz varias funçoes para fazer isso, mas me retorna sempre o seguinte erro ao clicar no heder .

**erro:
Additional information: O controlo DataGridView tem de ser vinculado a um objecto IBindingList para ser ordenado.**

alguem me pode ajudar por favor?